# SEO blog Indexing: wordpress.com subdomain vs a registered domain?

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-index

I've used WordPress for a few of my client's sites, mostly small businesses and eCommerce sites.  I have found through [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) as well as the [All in One Webmaster](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-webmaster/) plugin that when it comes to social media, using WordPress is a surefire way of getting your site indexed by Google and occasionally Bing and Yahoo.  Since I am a heavy WP user, I'd like to contribute by registering a dot WordPress domain for my portfolio.

When using a WP installation concurrently with a WP domain, e.g. `example.wordpress.com`, will the site be more or less likely to be indexed rather a generic `example.com` domain?

I've seen mixed opinions where people seem to favor a WP domain for URL output where others say that it's a moot point, and that Google will not favor a WP domain over a dot com domain as long as your meta tags are updated and content is keyword optimized.

I tend to disagree and believe a WP domain would more likely be indexed and output more URLs over an individual, laconic domain like `example.com`. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be any noticeable SEO difference between your own domain and a `wordpress.com sub-domain` in Google. Google ranks pages, not domains. Unless your domain is considered spam, it is a better option to host your blog/site in your domain.

In your own domain, you can install plugins to improve SEO by creating a XML sitemap. You can also choose a SEO optimized theme.

Having WordPress in your own domain will give you more freedom when installing plugins, chosing themes and run your own JavaScript.

`wordpress.com` subdomains are a better choice if you don't know (and you don't want to learn) how to install, update and upgrade WordPress.

Comment: Cheers Osvaldo, I ask because Wordpress.org is an authority site according to Google and has a reputable PageRank to be rekoned with .  I wonder if their PageRank would filter to WP blogs affiliated with Wordpress.org.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It doesn't. In these case, every subdomain has it's own pagerank.

Comment: Subdomains nor regular domains don't get PageRank. PageRank is *per page* not per site. Also, Google does n**not** see subdomains as separate websites.

Comment: I took both of your comments into consideration and decided to go with a dot com domain with a WP installation.  Thanks for the opinions guys.  *Mod please close thread*

Answer (score 1):

When you have `domain.wordpress.com` you're actually using a subdomain of someone else's domain; it has more advantages for them since you're promoting their domain with your content.

These days domains are so cheap (less than a cup of tea) it's better to have your own domain which will also have WordPress on the server but you don't have to see the `.wordpress` bit on your domain name if you buy your own paid domain.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, keywords in domain name have today less value than they used to. In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=rAWFv43qubI) Google explains why, and gives hints about how to choose domain.